# ListView get details of clicked row

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, onclick

android API 8.
I'd like to show some data in a listView and in following manner:
Item 1
-    Item 1.1
-    Item 1.2
Item 2
-    Item 2.1
-    Item 2.2
-    Item 2.3

So far i solved with a main ListView: each item is composed by a TextView (for items N) and a secondary ListView (inside a LinearLayout). For this list each item is a TextView (for items N.M).
I need, after the click of Item A.B, to retrieve its relative data and recall other Activity.
Now I defined the onClick(View) member inside the Activity that hosts the main ListView. This works but i don't know how to get the clicked row of the list and relative data from the View object.

Is it a good solution or does exist better?

Thanks!

Comment: you remade ExpandableListView from scratch!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)